# Expression<Func< - Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'lambda expression' and 'lambda expression'

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

How do I construct a LINQ WHERE clause that contains OR?

here is my code:

```
public static IQueryable<EmployeeObject> QueryableSQL()
{
    IQueryable<EmployeeObject> queryable = EmployeeRepository.GetAllEmployee(); 
}

public static IList<EmployeeObject> QLike(Expression<Func<EmployeeObject, bool>> func)
{
   return QueryableSQL().Where(func).ToList();
}
```

Calling like this:

```
QLike(t => t.Title == "stack" || t => t.Title == "over" || t => t.Title == "flow" ); <<<ERROR
```

or

```
QLike((t => t.Title == "stack") || (t => t.Title == "over") || (t => t.Title == "flow")); <<<ERROR
```

Error message:

> Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'lambda
>   expression' and 'lambda expression'

Comment: Why do you need Expression here at all? In this situation you just need Func.

Comment: the reason is that it will enable the LINQ provider to analyze the predicate and include it as part of the original SQL query. This can make a huge difference if your unfiltered result set is large. It could be the difference between reading a million records into memory or reading a single record.

Comment: Anyway, you've got all the correct answers below. "=>" must be just in the first part of the expression to pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass single lambda to method. Lambda expression syntax should looks like:

```
lambda-parameters => lambda-expression-body
```

So, here is correct syntax:

```
QLike(t => t.Title == "stack" || t.Title == "over" || t.Title == "flow" )
```

BTW looks like you can simplify your expression if you will use collection for titles you are looking for (depends whether `IQueryable` provider can translate this, e.g. EF provider translates such expressions into IN statement):

```
string[] titles = { "stack", "over", "flow" };
QLike(t => titles.Contains(t.Title));
```

Answer (score 1):

The method is expecting a *single* lambda expression, not multiple expressions. You need to apply the `||` operators to the individual boolean operations, like so:

```
QLike(t => t.Title == "stack" || t.Title == "over" || t.Title == "flow" );
```

Answer (score 1):

Call it this way:

```
QLike(t => t.Title == "stack" || t.Title == "over" || t.Title == "flow");
```

Because

```
t => t.Title == "stack"
```

is ONE func.

So

```
(t => t.Title == "stack") || (t => t.Title == "over")
```

are TWO funcs, and you applied an operator between them. This is the wrong syntax.